# VB/VBA If..ElseIf..Then, where each ElseIf..Then is on one line

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use Excel and string concatenation to do a little VB code generation of a mapping (value A and value B => value C). I'm actually going to insert the resulting VB code into a function in a Crystal Reports custom function that uses VB syntax.

In Excel, I have three columns containing the mapping values: The first two have the map's/function's input values, while the third has the output value. I filled these columns with a bunch of values (imagine that all the xxx, yyy, and zzz's are unique values).

A fourth column will be a string concatenation formula that implements the mapping in a giant VB If..ElseIf..ElseIf..ElseIf..EndIf statuement. Each row must generate an ElseIf..Then VB statement. I need to resulting code to look like below (I will manually type out the `If` line and the `EndIf` line.)

```
' This first line just lets all other lines be an "ElseIf" statement, making the Excel formula that renders this code the same for every entry.
If False Then foo = ""
ElseIf strProductCode = "xxx" And strPackageLength = "yyy" Then foo = "zzz"
ElseIf strProductCode = "xxx" And strPackageLength = "yyy" Then foo = "zzz"
ElseIf strProductCode = "xxx" And strPackageLength = "yyy" Then foo = "zzz"
ElseIf strProductCode = "xxx" And strPackageLength = "yyy" Then foo = "zzz"
EndIf
```

An example of the formula to generate the code would be something like:

```
="ElseIf strProductCode = """ & A1 & """ And strPackageLength = """ & B1 & """ then foo = """ & C1 & """"
```

The formula faithfully generates the VB. However, the above VB generates a syntax error:

"Compile error. Else without If"

Yes, I know that the `Then` portion is usually on a new line but is there some syntax that allows the code to be formatted as above, so that my Excel code generation formula does not have to resort to linefeeds in the formula?

Comment: The `foo = "zzz"` part cannot be on the same line as the `Then` if you are doing it that way.

Comment: The other option would be to put the entire if statement, including all the `ElseIf` parts, all on the same line, and surely you can see how impractical that would be.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements

Comment: If change the first line by putting whats after the "If False Then" on the next line "foo = "" It works. Probably VBA treats your first line as  single-line syntax where require multiple-line syntax.  Why I always indent and place things like that on the following line.  If it's "single-line syntax" I put in multiple-line syntax with and End If etc.  Single-line syntax can be bug prone.

Comment: delete `foo = ""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `Select Case` Instead of `If...ElseIf...End If`

[image]

**Excel Formula**

```
=REPT(" ",8)&"Case strProductCode = """&A1&""" And strPackageLength = """&B1&""": foo = """&C1&""""
```

**VBA Code**

```
Sub Test()

    Dim strProductCode As String: strProductCode = "A2"
    Dim strPackageLength As String: strPackageLength = "20"
    
    Dim foo As String

    Select Case True
        
        Case strProductCode = "A1" And strPackageLength = "10": foo = "C1"
        Case strProductCode = "A2" And strPackageLength = "20": foo = "C2"
        Case strProductCode = "A3" And strPackageLength = "30": foo = "C3"
        Case strProductCode = "A4" And strPackageLength = "40": foo = "C4"
        
        Case Else: foo = ""
    End Select

    MsgBox """foo"" is equal to """ & foo & """.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Turned out that Crystal Reports v14 Basic code syntax didn't like the colon's attempt to combine the two lines. Perhaps it is BASIC syntax and not VB syntax? In any event, perhaps you know how to appease Crystal. Syntactically, I found that the following works (note the `Else If`'s instead of `ElseIf`):

`If 1 = 2 Then getLowesSKU = "a" _
Else If 2 = 3 Then getLowesSKU = "b" _
Else If 3 = 3 Then getLowesSKU = "c" _
Else: If 4 = 4 Then getLowesSKU = "d"` Imagine four separate lines there.